# What's the correct term for a steam radiator valve pipe with tapered threads?

Tags: plumbing

In changing the air valves on antique steam radiator, I bought two different brands which both have machine-like straight threads, whereas the old ones reveal themselves to be tapered.

The new will not screw in. Assuming this is a mismatch and not a lost ability to screw, what is the plumbing terminology needed to shop for these devices?

Comment: A picture would probably help someone help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, most likely "**National Standard Taper Pipe**" Thread.

Elsewhere in the world most likely "**British Standard Pipe Taper**" Thread.